# Maatwebsite exports only the last line with unescaped data

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have a blade view that is the source for export to excel file.

Everything went perfect, but with unescaped data it printed only the last one.

Examples:

- {!! $data !!} : Display only the last one.
- {{ $data }} :  Display all but wrong format.

=> What do I do now?

[Maatwebsite export unescaped data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsAXK.png)

Comment: Try scrolling up in the text fields?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: The lower text fields, are you sure it is only showing the last one or that the box isn't big enough to show the content?

Comment: No, i checked it! it defenity one sentence(one row) in that cell.

Comment: I don't know then, sorry!

Comment: No problem! thanks for repplying :D